# SQL 3 - table query

Tags: mysql, sql

was wondering if you could help me out with a SQL problem.

Example of the tables, please ingore the lack of relationships its just an example.

http://postimg.org/image/5imvjgl0t/

Right so basically I want to get all the CustomerID's associated with a certain countrycode I can get that by doing a simple query on the customer table however I then need to find out how many forms the customer has submitted in the order table.

I then need to get the title of the warehouse (one warehouse per countrycode) and the number of customers associated with that warehouse who have submitted a form.

So in summary I need to get a list of customerID's from the Customer table and count how many time they show up in the Order table. sort them into the warehouse echo the warehouse title with the number of orders.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

P.S. please ignore any data type / relationship issues with the image above, it's just an example.

Comment: You may want to give some sample data and a desired result instead of linking to an image that no one can test against or verify that the result is correct. http://sqlfiddle.com/ is nice for setting up tests, but sample data and a desired result should be in the question for reference by future visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w.title, c.CustomerID, COUNT(o.form_id) as cnt
    FROM warehouse w
    JOIN customer c USING (countrycode)
    JOIN `Order` o USING (CustomerID)
    GROUP BY w.siteid, c.CustomerID
    ORDER BY w.title ASC, c.CustomerID
```

*edit*

If you want to include customers without any orders, you need a LEFT JOIN on the customers table:

```
SELECT w.title, c.CustomerID, COUNT(o.form_id) as cnt
    FROM warehouse w
    JOIN customer c USING (countrycode)
    LEFT JOIN `Order` o USING (CustomerID)
    GROUP BY w.countrycode, c.CustomerID
    ORDER BY w.title ASC, c.CustomerID
```

To filter for only one customer:

```
SELECT w.title, c.CustomerID, COUNT(o.form_id) as cnt
    FROM warehouse w
    JOIN customer c USING (countrycode)
    LEFT JOIN `Order` o USING (CustomerID)
    WHERE c.CustomerId = 2
    GROUP BY w.countrycode, c.CustomerID
    ORDER BY w.title ASC, c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Looks good, where would I place the WHERE statement? I tried putting it in under the JOINs but didn't work. I had 'WHERE o.CustomerID = "001" '

Comment: You might need to escape the name of the table Order since it's a reserved word but otherwise it should be fine. The WHERE should go after the JOINS and before the GROUP BY